# Semi-circle folded into a cone with a circular base

Tags: solid-geometry

From my 7th-grade math book:

> The semicircle shown is folded to form a right circular cone so that the arc PQ becomes the circumference of the base. Find the diameter of the base,

[image]

---

Let **$\text{circumference of cone base}=C$** and $\text{diameter}=d$.

I think the **diameter** should be $\frac{2C}{\pi}=\frac{2 \cdot 5cm}{\pi}\approx 3.183cm$. But my book's answer key says $d=2.5cm$, which seems to be half the circumference ($\frac{5cm}{2}$). But I don't get the reasoning behind it. The semicircle's diameter is the cone base's circumference. And if that's the circumference ($\frac{\pi d}{2}$), then the diameter should be $2C/\pi$, shouldn't it?

Why? I'm very confused. I feel the amount of information provided is insufficient somehow.

---

**The question is unique and original.** This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499725/bending-a-paper-sheet-to-a-cone) seems quite similar, with an answer which is appropriate in my case too. But the problem is the answer only states (facts I've already deduced), but doesn't *explain*.

Comment: You forgot to divide by 2.

Comment: The circumference of the circle the arc forms is not 5. Right approach but not the correct circumference.

Comment: @ntntnt Okay. Edited the question.

Comment: Circumference of the circle the arc forms is the length of the arc...which is $5\pi/2.$ I think you can calculate the diameter from there. Remember the circumference is $2\pi r.$

Answer (score 1):

So for the first part, you must find the circumference of the semicircle that is pictured (not including the straight side), which is $$c=0.5d\pi=2.5\pi$$
When the cone is formed, this circumference of the semicircle becomes the new circumference of the base of the cone, which is $$c=D\pi=2.5\pi$$ It can be implied that the diameter must be 2.5 centimeters.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The flat sector is folded to form a cone. Equating arc length before and after cone folding,

$$ 2 \pi r = L \theta,\; \sin \alpha = \frac{r}{L}$$

To eliminate $L$ multiply the equations and cancel $r$

$$\sin \alpha = \frac{\theta}{2 \pi}$$

The formula is adequate, can be used by sheet metal workers to make cones.

In our case

$$\sin \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2 \pi} = \frac12 \to \alpha = 30^{\circ}$$

so that when viewed sideways triangle $OPQ$ is equilateral,

$$ PQ=OP=OQ= L=\frac{5}{2}= 2.5 \;units. $$

If in case you want to make a cone with semi vertical angle $\alpha= 60^{\circ}$ then sector angle required from above formula is $ \theta = \pi \sqrt 3 $ radians or 311.77 degrees . One half of side view would appear as the triangle (60,30,90) degrees after roll folding shown at right.